# Status bar stops working part of the way through

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax, terminal

I am writing a timer program in bash and I want the status bar to change colors as it gets closer to completion.  The first (green) and second (yellow) third of the progress bar works as expected.  The last third (red) does not display correctly, but the counter keeps working.  What am I doing wrong in my syntax?

```
#!/bin/sh
#USAGE:
#timer <minutes>
clear

#add colors
RED='\033[0;31m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
LtGrn='\033[1;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

BAR='+###################+###################+###################'   # this is full bar, e.g. 60 chars

echo -e "${PURPLE}======================================================================${NC}"
echo
echo -e "                    Setting Timer for: ${YELLOW} $1 ${NC} minutes"
echo -e " ${PURPLE}  \o|           ${RED} 25%            ${YELLOW} 50%            ${GREEN} 75%            ${PURPLE} |o/ ${NC}"

for i in {1..60}; do
  if [ $i -ge 41 ]
    then
    echo -ne "\r ${RED}     ${BAR:41:$i}" # print $i chars of $BAR from 0 position
    sleep $1                              # wait 1/60th of total time between "frames"
  fi
  if [ $i -ge 21 ] && [ $i -lt 41 ]
    then
    echo -ne "\r ${YELLOW}     ${BAR:21:$i}" # print $i chars of $BAR from 0 position
    sleep $1                                 # wait 1/60th of total time between "frames"
  fi
  if [ $i -lt 21 ]
    then
    echo -ne "\r ${GREEN}     ${BAR:0:$i}" # print $i chars of $BAR from 0 position
    sleep $1                                 # wait 1/60th of total time between "frames"
  fi
done

echo
echo
echo -e "${RED}   Times up! Next task${NC}"
echo
```

Comment: A part of the problem is that you have the wrong shebang. It should be `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh` (`sh` does not support some of your constructs).

Comment: That's a typo, but not a problem - the script is posix

Comment: @KamilCuk No. For example, `echo` has no `-e` in POSIX specification. Not to talk about `${BAR:0:$i}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `${var:a:b}` extracts a substring **from** position `a` the count of `b` characters.

I guess you want `${BAR:0:$i}` in all cases.

```
echo -ne "\r ${RED}     ${BAR:0:$i}"
echo -ne "\r ${YELLOW}     ${BAR:0:$i}"
```

`${BAR:21:$i}` just happens to work, because `${#BAR}` is long enough.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks for the help and explanation